# how to hide one of the duplicated titles?

Tags: php

i have this code and i want to add a filter that hide one of duplicated items with the same "notizie.Titolo"

```
<?php
$rezultatet = mysql_query("SELECT  notizie.Data, notizie.Id_Foto, notizie.Titolo, notizie.IDNotizia, categorie.NomeCategoria
FROM notizie 
JOIN categorie ON  notizie.IDCategoria=categorie.IDCategoria 
WHERE notizie.IDCategoria 
IN (2795,2686,2706,2720,2719,2688,2787,2785,2786,2789,2788,2790,2796,2781,2782,2797,2777,2778,2780,2775,2779,2776,2784,2783,2793,2794,2792,2791) 
ORDER BY Data desc LIMIT 50 
");
```

Comment: Try with `GROUP BY notizie.Titolo`.

Comment: Use `GROUP BY notizie.Titolo`

Comment: can u please write how should be the code , cuz it show warnings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
$rezultatet = mysql_query("SELECT  notizie.Data, notizie.Id_Foto, notizie.Titolo, notizie.IDNotizia, categorie.NomeCategoria
FROM notizie 
JOIN categorie ON  notizie.IDCategoria=categorie.IDCategoria 
WHERE notizie.IDCategoria 
IN (2795,2686,2706,2720,2719,2688,2787,2785,2786,2789,2788,2790,2796,2781,2782,2797,2777,2778,2780,2775,2779,2776,2784,2783,2793,2794,2792,2791) 
GROUP BY notizie.Titolo
ORDER BY notizie.Data desc LIMIT 50 
");
```

Comment: it shows error warning : mysql_fetch_array():supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in ....

Answer (score 1):

Wether you should use a GROUP BY or a SELECT DISTINCT statement. Have a look at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/distinct-optimization.html or http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/group-by-extensions.html.

Answer (score 0):

You can use :

```
SELECT  notizie.Data, notizie.Id_Foto, notizie.Titolo, notizie.IDNotizia, categorie.NomeCategoria
FROM notizie 
JOIN categorie ON  notizie.IDCategoria=categorie.IDCategoria 
WHERE notizie.IDCategoria 
IN (...) 
GROUP BY notizie.Titolo
ORDER BY Data desc LIMIT 50
```

or

```
 SELECT  DISTINCT notizie.Titolo, notizie.Data, notizie.Id_Foto, notizie.IDNotizia, categorie.NomeCategoria
    FROM notizie 
    JOIN categorie ON  notizie.IDCategoria=categorie.IDCategoria 
    WHERE notizie.IDCategoria 
    IN (...) 
    ORDER BY Data desc LIMIT 50
```